# The return value at recursive fun at Python

Tags: python-3.x

im trying to write a function that takes as a value a dict,
and return if the key is exists at the dict.
i debugged the function and i fount out that even if the function
enter a code where it should return True, it is still calling the other recursive calls,
and return none instead of the initial True value.

the function:

```
def checkIfKeyExsists(self,searchKey,passingValue):
        if searchKey in passingValue:
            return True
        else:
        
            for value in passingValue.values():
                
                if type(value) == dict:
                    if searchKey in value.keys():
                        print("yes")
                        return  True
                    else:
                        self.checkIfKeyExsists(searchKey,value)
                        
                elif type(value) == list:
                    for dicInLst in value:
                        self.checkIfKeyExsists(searchKey,dicInLst)
```

dict that i used:

```
thisdict = {
  "brand": "Ford",
  "model": {"Mustang":{"car":"motti","car123":"34"}},
  "year": [{"a":"test"},{"c":"er"}] }      
   
jn = JsonNode(thisdict)
x = jn.checkIfKeyExsists("car",jn.getJsonDic())
```

**this function is a part of class that calls JsonNode

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are three issues with your recursive function.

First you don't return anything at the end of your function.  So what does happen if you don't fall in the different branches of your code? Then the function will return None as you experienced.  So first you should terminate your function with `return False`.

Second you don't do anything of the value returned by your recursive calls. Hence this value is just ignored.  So this why even when the key is found, you keep performing recursive calls.  You should do something like this instead:  replace

```py
self.checkIfKeyExsists(searchKey,dicInLst)
```

by

```py
if(self.checkIfKeyExsists(searchKey,dicInLst)):
   return True
```

Last, it does not affect the correctness of your function but your check `if searchKey in value.keys()` is actually useless as it's already performed as the first test (`if searchKey in passingValue`) when performing a recursive call.  Hence this case will be covered by your recursive call (`self.checkIfKeyExsists(searchKey,value)`).

Comment: Hi,i added a parameter to the function as a return value and now it is working.

Comment: yes that's another solution, but then you'll still keep performing recursive calls even if you've found the key in your dictionary.